# Chrome renders differently from Chrome on another machine

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering

I might be missing something very obvious, but
somehow Chrome on one machine (client, Windows 10 laptop)
does not render/output part of the code that is rendered
without problem on other machines 
(tried Chrome on Win7, Win10, MacOS, Centos8).

I was just brought on to fix up a CodeIgniter implementation
by other devs - it seems they used bootstrap. All of the Javascript files in the html header are loading normally, so that is not the issue.

This is what it **should** look like logged out (show [noauth] in the red bar)

[image: logged out]

This is what it should look like when logged in (show stuff in the red bar)

[image: logged in]

However, the client's machine shows nothing in the red bar.

I checked the source code on the problematic machine's 
computer, and the logout menu code is right there, so the
server code is not the issue.

Excerpt from the problematic client machine's browser source:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-topbar navbar-dark mk-header-toolbar">
  <div class="col mk-grid mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-9 d-none d-md-block d-sm-block">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mt-1" style='font-size: .75rem;'>
          <li class='nav-item'>
            <i class='fa fa-phone text-white'></i>
          </li>
          <li class='nav-item ml-2'>
            <a class='text-white' href='tel:+222'>222</a>
          </li>
          <li class='nav-item ml-2'>
            <a class='text-white' href='tel:+222'>222</a>
          </li>
          <li class='nav-item ml-2'>
            <i class='fa fa-envelope text-white'></i>
            <a class='ml-2 text-white' href="mailto:xxx">xxx</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 mk-header-social">
        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row-reverse">


          [noauth]
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Might there be another reason why the "[noauth]" will not be shown in one machine, but in all others I have tested?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the **mk-header-social** class was the culprit.
I still do not know why that is. I did a quick search in the .css
files, and there are just too many instructions connected to this
tag ( I was hired to fix up a site a previous developer had started
but not finished ).

I do see that depending on context, the visibility is set as hidden
or visible, and they play with opacity, so the behavior makes sense
in that respect, though why Chrome would render differently on different
machines is still a puzzle.